# How to add a pseudo aesthetic argument to ggplot2 geom?

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I have and what I want:

```
data<- data.frame(value= 1:10, Treatment= rep(c("A", "B"),5), Species=rep(c("alpha", "beta"), each=5))
```

And it is known to all that `ggplot2::aes()` function can automatically group the data according to the arguments it quotes, for example, `ggplot(data=data)+geom_boxplot(aes(y= value, x= Treatment, fill=Treatment))` separates and groups data by `Treatment` [image: plot1]

and is plotted as **2** different boxes. In like manner `ggplot(data=data)+geom_boxplot(aes(y= value, x= Treatment, fill=Treatment, linetype= Species))` will generate **4** boxes grouped by both Teatment and Species with different color filling and linetype respectively [image: plot2].

However, how to generate a boxplot of **4** boxes grouped by `Treatment` and `Species` in which `Treatment` is presented by filling color same as the plot metioned above, but Species was not presented, that is,  the linetype is all the same among boxes? In other words, is there a null aesthetic only group the data but never be presented on the plot.

Comment: there's a group aesthetic

Comment: I tried and the `group` argument destroyed the grouping and color filling by other aesthetics resulting a plain monocolor plot only present aes(group= Species) eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
ggplot(data=data)+
  geom_boxplot(aes(y= value, x= Treatment, fill=Treatment)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

Comment: Facet is a good alternative, but the 4 boxes are not exactly located on the same (sub) plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new variable that has 4 levels either in your data or on the fly as I have shown below.  With this you will get the 4 box plots, colored and grouped as you asked for.  No matter what you will probably need to distinguish the data in some way, either on the axis labels or in the legend.

```
ggplot(data=data)+geom_boxplot(aes(y= value, x= Treatment, fill=Treatment, group=paste(Species, Treatment))
```

[image]

Comment: That's a quite excellent solution, but it only works in the situation that x-axis is presenting one of the grouping factors. When it comes to geom_line or goem_smooth with both x and y presenting values instead of grouping factors is there any solution?

Comment: I updated my answer to use grouping.  I think that will also work for geom_line and geom_smooth

Comment: It seems we thinks alike, LOL. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the solutions of J Hart and baptiste,  `ggplot(data=data)+geom_boxplot(aes(y= value, x= Treatment, fill=Treatment, group= paste(Treatment, Species)))` works perfectly.